# QGIS - the TIFF has lost its colors

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I recently updated the Qgsi version to 3.28.12. In the previous version I correctly displayed drone images in tiff:
[image]
but now it shows them as shown in the photo.
[image]

I tried changing the image symbology settings and checking the rendering preferences but I didn't find anything strange.
following the instructions in a post I also converted the file but nothing changes
Any indication is welcome

Comment: Can you post the file?  I can give it a try to see if it is a systematic issue.  Also, if you right click the layer, can you check the properties?

Comment: the tif weighs 400Mb , It's a Int16 and sRGB (maybe this is the problem?)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BvE8YBpKQFbjE3oyt7al8gJqZbF-TQ0d/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y0GXvu4q-jK1o9aJIucujMtMLVAjdK3v/view?usp=sharing  Can you drag these in?  The linked georeferenced tiff worked on my QGIS

Comment: When I right click that one and look at the properties, i can see the Driver as GDAL.   Is that what you have?

Comment: In your file and mine too I read  gdal. Your file is good . I don't understand why

Comment: Did you open an existing project or start a new project and pull in the geotiff?  I have had this before also but I do not remember what I did to fix it.  In the QGIS Raster Menu there is a convert.

Comment: I tried both ways and also converted the file using RASTER >Convert

Comment: I solved the problem by exporting the image from a less updated version of Qgis. The new tif image loads without any problems. Thank you anyway for your availability